# From Cartan-Weyl matrix to structure constants

Tags: rt.representation-theory, kac-moody-algebras

Assume that some Cartan-Weyl matrix $A_{ij}$ (of a Kac-Moody algebra, not necessarily a semisimple Lie algebra!) is given. Since it completely determines the algebra, it must completely determine the structure constants $f_{ij}^k$ (up to gauge, i.e. with some generator set $\{e_i\}$, $[e_i,e_j]=\sum{e_k}f_{ij}^k$). *In principle* I could do this myself from Wiki infos, in reality I'd need a math studium. Can someone demonstrate the technique for $A_{ij}=((2,-1),(-4,2))$, the probably most simple case, even if infinitely many generators result for a Kac-Moody algebra?

Comment: What do you mean by structure constants?

Comment: Isn't that a standard terminus technicus for Lie algebras? Anyway, I edit it in.

Comment: As explained on the Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kac%E2%80%93Moody_algebra), Kac-Moody algebras are *defined* in terms of (a finite number of) generators and relations. [By the way, they are by definition Lie algebras; I think you mean to say "not necessarily a semisimple Lie algebra."] In other words, they are a certain quotient of a free Lie algebra on a finite set of generators. However, except for the semisimple Lie algebras, they are not finite-dimensional as vector spaces. They will have infinitely many basis elements.

Comment: Semisimple, of course. Still, even if infinitely-dimensional, this surely can be "summed up" by properly indexing the generators for this simple example?!

Comment: What's confusing is: are you talking about how to "multiply" (i.e., take the Lie bracket of) *generators* of the K-M algebra *as a Lie algebra*; or are you talking about how to multiply *basis elements* for some choice of basis. Usually when one speaks of "structure constants" for an algebra they mean in terms of a basis. But even indexing a basis of a K-M algebra is a quite nontrivial task, because it is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: @SamHopkins: Wait, generators=!=basis? (I know so little...) But I immediately believe the nontriviality of the task, which sort of answers my question. Maybe I should ask about an "infinite toy basis" first.